# Fail to connect Multiple Sphero using Android

Tags: android, connection, sphero

I try to run the MicroSample provided in the Android SDK to connect two Sphero 2.0. The two Sphero are listed in SpheroConnectionView, but when I click them to connect, the SpheroConnectionView disappear directly and there is only ONE Sphero are connected.

I tried to force the SpheroConnectionView to show again by using mSpheroConnectionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); I can see only one is connected, if I click another unconnected one, nothing happens (no connection event, no fail or disconnect event either).

I tested it on both Samsung Tab Pro 8.4 and Motorola Moto G (both Androind 4.4.2), and it is the same. I tried the Sphero Multi Drive from Google Play on both devices, and it can connected two Sphero. (Although on Moto g the app automatically crush very quickly after serval seconds)

Anyone connect multiple Spheros successfully ?

Thank you very much.